# Error while using bandpass function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bandpass-filter

I am trying to make a [superheterodyne receiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheterodyne_receiver) in Matlab. This is the block diagram given in my book:

[image]

I have implemented the modulation of signal :

```
freq_message = 1;
freq_carrier = 10;

w_message = 2*pi*freq_message;
w_carrier = 2*pi*freq_carrier;

message_signal = 5*cos(w_message*time);
carrier_signal = 10*cos(w_carrier*time);

modulated = message_signal .* carrier_signal;
```

Now I wish to add a band pass filter at the beginning of the receiver and I tried using the [in-build](https://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bandpass.html) `bandpass` function:

```
err = 1; % bandpass freq_carrier-err to freq_carrier+err
out_bandpass = bandpass(modulated,[freq_carrier-err,freq_carrier+err]);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error using signal.internal.filteringfcns.parseAndValidateInputs>validateParameters (line 229)
Normalized passband frequency values must be in the (0,1) interval. Use a value in the (0,1) interval or specify a sample rate.

Error in signal.internal.filteringfcns.parseAndValidateInputs (line 98)
opts = validateParameters(opts);

Error in bandpass (line 103)
opts = signal.internal.filteringfcns.parseAndValidateInputs(x,'bandpass',varargin);

Error in untitled (line 66)
out_bandpass = bandpass(modulated,[freq_carrier-err,freq_carrier+err]);
```

Comment: `bandpass` is for *digital* filters.  This is not so.

Comment: @rayryeng what should I use then?

Comment: Nothing :)  You will have to make it yourself!

Comment: @rayryeng ok... thanks... I will try :-)